# Powershell get-childitem exclude directory several levels deep

Tags: powershell

I have a folder containing changed files to deploy to another server. I am building a list of files below the root, recursively, and I want to skip an entire folder. This is not working:

```
gci -path \\myfolder -recurse -exclude "*\excludeme\*" | where{! $_PSIsContainer}
```

It is going ahead and listing all the files in excludeme as well. Even this didn't work:

```
gci -path \\myfolder -recurse -exclude "\\myfolder\excludeme\*" | where etc.
```

I should note that "excludeme" is a folder that contains a number of software project folders, i.e. a whole mess of subfolders in itself. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use -Exclude if you simple enter the name of the folder:

```
GCI \\MyFolder -Recurse -Exclude "ExcludeMe"
```

With that said, if it doesn't work for you (and it wouldn't surprise me, because the File System Provider is horrible at filtering IMHO), you can always filter after you get the results, it will just be a little slower:

```
GCI \\MyFolder -Recurse | Where{$_.FullName -NotMatch "\\ExcludeMe(\\|$)"}
```

Comment: Hot dog, that second one worked. Using -exclude just goes ahead and catches all the files under that folder. Thanks!